# I can create a project with API22 But I can not create project with API8 in android studio

Tags: android, android-studio

I have android studio 1.3 and I asked a question in this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32126160/why-i-can-not-create-a-project-in-android-studio-1-3) and finally I fond the my problem and the solution. When I want to create a project when the `Minimum SDK` is the `API22`, I can create my new project successfully. But When I create a project that the `Minimum SDK` is `API8` I can not create my new project and I get the same problem that there was in the above link. Now, I want to create my new project that the `Minimum SDK` is `API8`, What should I add in my `sdk` folder?

Comment: Do you have API 18 in your SDK?

Comment: Yes, because when I want to create project when  the `Minimum API` is `18`, I am successful.

Comment: but you said: "But When I create a project that the Minimum SDK is API8 I can not create my new project "

Comment: it is very  strange . I tested with `API8` again and now it did not stop and I can create my project successfully with some errors, of course. I want a link that I can download the complete `sdk` and without Shortage.